# Unexpected Addition Behaviour of two Uint64

Tags: go

**Problem**

In the code below, I have a couple of Go-routines and the one I'm facing issues with is the "calculateMemoryUsage()" Go-routine, where the avg memory usage is to be calculated every half a second. For some reason, the total keeps giving me weird values. Here's the Print Logs:

```
Memory Usage: 162224
Average: 162224
Total: 162224
Iteration Count: 1

Memory Usage: 181200
Average: 171712
Total: 343424
Iteration Count: 2

Memory Usage: 187864
Average: 119858
Total: 359576
Iteration Count: 3
```

As seen, from the third iteration, the average messes up because the total doesn't add right. After debugging, I see that the memory usage is read fine, but the total seems to give me issues. I suspected the GC, but during this problem the LastGC value is set to 0, meaning no GC is performed. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! :)

**Code**

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "<credentials_removed>@@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/rts")

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    showStocksChannel := make(chan bool)
    showBestPerformingChannel := make(chan bool)



    go calculateMemoryUsage()
    go showStocks(showStocksChannel, db)
    go changeStockPrices(showStocksChannel, showBestPerformingChannel, db)
    go displayBestPerformingStocks(showBestPerformingChannel, db)

    showStocksChannel <- true

    select{}
}
func calculateMemoryUsage() {
    var averageMemoryUsage uint64 = 0
    var iterations uint64 = 0
    var usage uint64 = 0
    var total uint64 = 0

    for iterations <= 200 {
        var memoryStats runtime.MemStats
        runtime.ReadMemStats(&memoryStats)

        iterations = iterations + 1

        usage = memoryStats.Alloc
        total = (averageMemoryUsage + usage)
        averageMemoryUsage = total / iterations

        fmt.Printf("\nMemory Usage: %v\nAverage: %v\nTotal: %v\nIteration Count: %v\n\n", usage, averageMemoryUsage, total, iterations)



        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
        //fmt.Printf("\nLast GC: %v\nNext GC: %v\n\n", memoryStats.LastGC, memoryStats.NextGC)


    }

    fmt.Printf("\nAverage Memory Usage: %v bytes\n\n", averageMemoryUsage)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
total = (averageMemoryUsage + usage)
```

should be

```
total = (total + usage)
```